# WebEye.Controls.Wpf.WebCameraControl - Camera Preview is not coming

Tags: c#, wpf, camera

I have used WebEye.Controls.Wpf.WebCameraControl for the camera control to capture images. And I can able to capture images as well with it. But the video streaming (that is the preview of the image capture) is not coming for the camera.

```
<Window x:Class="Hybrid.BEST.Tech.App.View.Camera"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup- 
 compatibility/2006"
                    xmlns:wpf="clr- namespace:WebEye.Controls.Wpf; assembly=WebEye.Controls.Wpf.WebCameraControl"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="550">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="94*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Width="115.333" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" />
                    <!--<Button x:Name="startButton" Content="Start" Width="75" Margin="4,0,0,0" IsEnabled="False" Click="OnStartButtonClick" />
                    <Button x:Name="stopButton" Content="Stop" Width="75" Margin="4,0,0,0" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsCapturing, ElementName=webCameraControl}" Click="OnStopButtonClick" />-->
                    <Button x:Name="imageButton" Content="CapturePicture" Width="90" Margin="4,0,0,0" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsCapturing, ElementName=webCameraControl}" Click="OnImageButtonClick" />
                </StackPanel>
                <wpf:WebCameraControl x:Name="webCameraControl" Height="400" />
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
        </Window>
```

Comment: Is the camera started?

Comment: yes, started and I can able to capture images as well. only problem is with the video stream the display.

Comment: Is the streaming images coming over the internet?  I do not see any code that binds the grid to the stream.

Comment: public partial class Camera : Window
    {
        private WebCameraId _cameraID = null;
        public string filepath = "";
        public Camera()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeComboBox();
            StartCamera();
        }        
        private void StartCamera()
        {
            var cameraId = (WebCameraId)comboBox.SelectedItem;
            webCameraControl.StartCapture(cameraId);
        }

Comment: This is the back end code I added. It is working to capture the images but the video streaming before the capture is not coming

Comment: We need to find out three things 1) Is streaming data coming over the internet.  Using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler will determine if the data is coming over the internet 2) If Data is not coming then did a command get sent to camera to start the data stream 3) If data is coming over internet, is reading from the internet is failing or writing to the control is failing.

Comment: I am using the camera in my local to capture image offline. And I can capture it, but the display is not coming. I mean the streaming from my own camera. My requirement is to capture my image only. And it is not a chat of meeting in the web.

Comment: You are still connecting to the camera over internet.  There is a client connection to the camera with an IP and port number.  You want the stream from the client connection to go to the display.  Correct?  There is a different of capturing one frame and streaming multiple frames.  I don't know if a single capture send a command to camera to get one frame, or the single capture is just getting one from from a running stream.  So I do not know if the stream is running.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an issue with Windows 10; I've tested it on a tablet running 10 v 1703 and it works fine, but the preview doesn't work on a tablet using Window 10 v 1809 (both of which had no internet access, but was streaming directly from the camera installed in the device).  I've added it as an [issue on their GitHub page](https://github.com/jacobbo/WebEye/issues/62).

**Update:** I ended up using a different github project using Accord.Video and Accord.Video.DirectShow.  It isn't as out-of-the-box as the WebEye, but that also gave me more flexibility than WebEye.  [You can find an example here](https://www.mesta-automation.com/getting-started-with-computer-vision-in-c-sharp/)

Why did I go to this solution, you may ask?  The web cam that I was trying to connect to has stupidly high resolution (~3600X2400 pixels).  On newer versions of Windows 10, WebEye would just through its hands up in the air and not show anything.  The replacement that the developer was working on would show a preview, but with a 6-8 second delay and the application he gave me to test would lock up as soon as you tried to take a picture, change camera, close the application, etc.

With no solution on that end, I went hunting for another one.  The Accord classes worked with only a 0.5-1 second lag on the preview and didn't lock the app.  The downside was that it consumes ~30% of CPU and 1 GB of active memory while the preview is running.